# How can I check how much traffic my code can handle?

Tags: php, scale

I am programming a website (in php) and I wonder how I can test and learn how much traffic my code can handle?

Comment: Use the Apache benchmark tool :-)

Comment: Some colleagues of mine are setting up a cluster of servers on Amazon's cloud to simulate load on our service. They might all appear to come from the same IP, so it's not perfect, but it's a start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to perform load testing. You can use

1. [Aapache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
2. Siege
3. Apache Benchmark (`ab`)

Among the three JMeter is better and its my recommendation. I never used `ab`.